# apk upload showing 0 supported devices

Tags: android, apk, manifest

On uploading an update for my program I'm getting 0 supported devices, I have tried to remove all permissions as suggested in other posts still the problem shows.

Kindly find below the manifest used:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.companyname.appnameForAndroid"
android:versionCode="4031"
android:versionName="4.31" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<application
    android:name="com.companyname.appnameForAndroid.appnameApp"
  android:icon="@drawable/icon"
  android:allowBackup="false"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
     >
    
    <activity
        android:name="com.companyname.appnameForAndroid.appname"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.companyname.appnameForAndroid.sampleBooksActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.companyname.appnameForAndroid.BookReader"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
         />
    <activity
        android:name="com.companyname.appnameForAndroid.TOCTabLayout"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.companyname.appnameForAndroid.TOCActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.companyname.appnameForAndroid.HighlightsActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.companyname.appnameForAndroid.SearchActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.companyname.appnameForAndroid.BookmarksActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.companyname.appnameForAndroid.notesActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.companyname.appnameForAndroid.loadAllActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.companyname.appnameForAndroid.appnameLibrary"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.companyname.appnameForAndroid.loadBooksActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.companyname.appnameForAndroid.loadBooksActivityTest"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    
    <activity
        android:name="com.companyname.appnameForAndroid.settingActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
     <activity
        android:name="com.companyname.appnameForAndroid.restoreBooksActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
     
     <activity 
         android:name="com.companyname.appnameForAndroid.timerActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         />

     <activity 
         android:name="com.companyname.appnameForAndroid.studentInfoActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         />

     <activity 
         android:name="com.companyname.appnameForAndroid.searchListActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         />
     
     <activity 
         android:name="com.companyname.appnameForAndroid.bookSettingsActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         />
     
     <activity 
         android:name="com.companyname.appnameForAndroid.DictActivity"
         android:configChanges="orientation"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         />

     <activity 
         android:name="com.companyname.appnameForAndroid.footNoteActivity"
         android:configChanges="orientation"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         />
    
     <activity 
         android:name="com.companyname.appnameForAndroid.helpActivity"
         android:configChanges="orientation"
         android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         />
    <meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="30c1eff5acac28fff9b34dd529486994ea12c4ea" />


    <activity
        android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.ShareEmailActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/tw__transparent"
        android:label="@string/kit_name" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.digits.sdk.android.PhoneNumberActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:taskAffinity="com.digits.sdk.android"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.digits.sdk.android.ConfirmationCodeActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:taskAffinity="com.digits.sdk.android"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.digits.sdk.android.LoginCodeActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:taskAffinity="com.digits.sdk.android"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.digits.sdk.android.PinCodeActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:taskAffinity="com.digits.sdk.android"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.digits.sdk.android.FailureActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:taskAffinity="com.digits.sdk.android" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.digits.sdk.android.ContactsActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.digits.sdk.android.PhoneNumberActionBarActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:taskAffinity="com.digits.sdk.android"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.digits.sdk.android.ConfirmationCodeActionBarActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:taskAffinity="com.digits.sdk.android"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.digits.sdk.android.LoginCodeActionBarActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:taskAffinity="com.digits.sdk.android"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.digits.sdk.android.FailureActionBarActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:taskAffinity="com.digits.sdk.android" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.digits.sdk.android.ContactsActionBarActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.digits.sdk.android.PinCodeActionBarActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:taskAffinity="com.digits.sdk.android"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible" />

    <service
        android:name="com.digits.sdk.android.ContactsUploadService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.companyname.appnameForAndroid.reviewBook"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.companyname.appnameForAndroid.bookInfoReview"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.companyname.appnameForAndroid.appnameLibrarysub"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.companyname.appnameForAndroid.subscriptionsActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.companyname.appnameForAndroid.subscriptionsDetailsActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

</application>

</manifest>
```

Kindly note that when I submit it shows that I am using the following features:

```
    android.hardware.FAKETOUCH
    android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT
```

and the following permissions:

```
    android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
    android.permission.INTERNET
    android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
    android.permission.VIBRATE
    android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
    android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
    com.companyName.appNameForAndroid.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
```

Knowing that in my Android manifest some of the permissions don't exist and and I am not using any feature.

Comment: This is a bug in Google Play Store. Don't worry about it (already answered 10 times in those 3 days :D)

Comment: Check also the build.gradle file for supported versions. You might have some error there, probably. Check, just in case

Comment: @MatPag so this bug would be solved soon?

Comment: @ValdioVeliu The build.gradle was not modified since last version, I'm just fixing something minor but thank you for your suggestion

Comment: @coder Yes we hope it will be resolved soon. In the meantime you can publish your app without any worry, the supported devices will be updated after your publication is published

Comment: @MatPag I prefer to wait to make sure the devices are supported, thank you for your update.

Comment: @MatPag The problem is still showing.

Comment: You are not alone... Seems that Google has not resolved the problem yet

Comment: @MatPag Thank for your update I added a certain update just to clarify things to make sure it's nothing on my side.

Comment: @MatPag Yes you were right, kindly write your comment as an answer so I may accept it, and thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @coder done ;) and good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem of Google Play actually, probably will be fixed in a few days.

Answer (score 1):

As for the extra features and permissions not listed in your manifest, those can come from your dependancies (Support Library, Play Services, Firebase etc.).

Comment: Thank you for your enlightenment.